# Swagger/OpenAPI documentation for multiple Azure Function Apps (v4) - IN PROCESS MODEL - projects present in single solution

Tags: azure-functions, swagger, .net-6.0, openapi

I would like to request assistance with using OpenAPI for a solution where I have multiple Azure Functions Apps projects (**In process model**). My solution has one common Startup.cs file added to each of the projects as a Project Reference. I am using .NET 6.

I have installed **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi** for all Azure Function App projects and the project with the Startup file (the Startup project contains only this class + configuration).

When I run a single function locally, the documentation is generated. However, when I run my entire local server, I receive an empty page. (Empty page also occurred for case with projects published to Azure Function App on Azure)

Is it possible to generate documentation for my scenario? Do I need to add any additional configuration?

Sample solution structure:
Server.sln

- AzFuncApp1.csproj - proj ref to StartupProject.csproj

  - Function11.cs
  - Function12.cs
- AzFuncApp2.csproj - proj ref to StartupProject.csproj

  - Function21.cs
  - Function22.cs
- StartupProject.csproj

  - StartupClass.cs

For the functions I'm interested in, I have added:

```
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "AddTags")]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
[OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(IReadOnlyList<InsertTagRequest>),
    Description = "JSON request body containing { hours, capacity}")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(StatusResponse),
    Description = "Statuses:\n\r - 0 - Ok status,\n\r - 1 - test")]
```

Is it possible to generate documentation for my scenario? Do I need to add any additional configuration?

Here you can find an example project with the described flow of how I run functions from multiple projects: https://github.com/DawidKuzminski/SwaggerInMultipleAzureProjectsInProcess

I want to achieve one of the solutions:

1. hit https://serverUrl/api/swagger/ui and see all endpoints
2. have openAPI endpoint per family of functions: eg:

- https://serverUrl/api/AzFuncApp1/swagger/ui,
- https://serverUrl/api/AzFuncApp2/swagger/ui